# I'm trying to make an op-1a pattern mxf file from an interleaved 5.1 BWF file. Must be audio only. Any ideas?

Tags: ffmpeg, mxf

I've used quite a few commercial products over the years to create mxf files for various application (OP-atom, OP-1a, AS02, IMF, DCP, etc) but now I need to find a CLI method (preferably open source) to wrap a 5.1 PCM interleaved audio track as an OP-1a mxf file.

This is possible from a number of editing and mastering tools, but I need to incorporate this function into an automated pipeline and unfortunately, ffmpeg will not make an OP-1a without a video track. I have created a dummy video for other applications where the file spec isn't as stringent, but in this case I need a single interleaved BWF (or Stereo, depending on the source) muxed into an OP-1a MXF by itself (with the requisite MXF timecode, metadata, etc).

Any suggestions?